# How to get nested value from @vercel/edge-config

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have keys like this:

```
{
  "redirects": {
    "/us/blog/second-marriage-in-islam-without-permission-of-first-wife": "/blog/punishment-for-second-marriage-without-divorce-in-islam",
  }
}
```

How can I get the `redirects['/us/blog/second-marriage-in-islam-without-permission-of-first-wife']` in a single request without loading all the redirects using `get('redirects')` ?

**Note: Root keys may consist of alphanumeric characters, "-" and "_" only**

So I cannot add redirects in the root key.

I tried adding keys in root but it didn't work.

Vercel error: Root keys may consist of alphanumeric characters, "-" and "_" only